# Autowired service marks Null pointer exception when running tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-test

I marked a service as @autowired in my test class. I have two tests using this service, **only one of this test is not working**; it's throwing NullpointerException. So basically its's like if the service it's "partially autowired".

Here's the test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MainApplication.class)
class ServiceLayerTests {
    
    @Autowired
    private DocumentoService documentsService;

    @Autowired
    private InstitucionService institutionService;

    @MockBean
    private DocumentoRepository documentsRepo;

    @MockBean
    private InstitucionRepository institutionsRepo;

    @Test
    void whenCreateDocument_ReturnDocument() {
        Documento entityDoc = TestUtils.generateDocumentObject(1l, "redbanc", "bcochile");
        when(documentsRepo.save(entityDoc)).thenReturn(entityDoc);

        DocumentoVo docVo = TestUtils.generateDocumentVoObject(1l, "redbanc", "bcochile");
        DocumentoVo actualDocument = documentsService.uploadFile(docVo);
        System.out.println(actualDocument);
        assertEquals(entityDoc.getIdDocumento(), actualDocument.getId());
    }

    @Test
    void whenFindDocumentById_ReturnDocument() {
        Long id = 1l;
        Documento entityDoc = TestUtils.generateDocumentObject(1l, "redbanc", "bcochile");
        Optional<Documento> optionalEntityDoc = Optional.of(entityDoc);
        when(documentsRepo.findById(id)).thenReturn(optionalEntityDoc);

        DocumentoVo actualDocument = documentsService.findDocumentById(id).get();
        assertEquals(entityDoc.getIdDocumento(), actualDocument.getId());
    }

    @Test
    void whenFindInstitutions_ReturnInstitutions() {
        
        Institucion[] institutions = TestUtils.generateInstitucionArray();
        Iterable<Institucion> iterableInstitutions = Arrays.asList(institutions);
        when(institutionsRepo.findAll()).thenReturn(iterableInstitutions);

        List<InstitucionVo> actualInstitution = institutionService.getInstituciones();

        assertEquals(institutions.length, actualInstitution.toArray().length);
    }
}
```

Here's the service:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class DocumentoService {

    @Autowired
    private DocumentoRepository documentsRepo;

    public DocumentoVo uploadFile(DocumentoVo file) {
        Documento doc = transformDocumentToEntity(file);

        return VoBuilderFactory.getDocumentoVoBuilder(documentsRepo.save(doc)).build();
    }

    public Optional<DocumentoVo> findDocumentById(Long id) {
        Optional<Documento> documento = documentsRepo.findById(id);
        Optional<DocumentoVo> docVO = Optional.empty();
        if (documento.isPresent()) {
            DocumentoVo docTemp = VoBuilderFactory.getDocumentoVoBuilder(documento.get()).build();
            docVO = Optional.of(docTemp);
        }

        return docVO;
    }

    private Documento transformDocumentToEntity(DocumentoVo file) {
        Documento doc = new Documento();
        doc.setNomDocumentoSti(file.getNomDocumentoSti());
        doc.setNomDocumentoUsuario(file.getNomDocumentoUsuario());
        doc.setHashDocumento(file.getHashDocumento());

        TipoDocumentoVo tipoDocVo = file.getTipoDocumento();
        TipoDocumento tipoDoc = new TipoDocumento();
        tipoDoc.setIdTipoDocumento(tipoDocVo.getId());
        tipoDoc.setDescripcionTipoDocumento(tipoDocVo.getDescripcion());

        doc.setTipoDocumento(tipoDoc);

        EstadoDocumentoVo estadoDocVo = file.getEstadoDocumento();
        EstadoDocumento estadoDoc = new EstadoDocumento();
        estadoDoc.setIdEstado(estadoDocVo.getId());
        estadoDoc.setDescEstado(estadoDocVo.getDescripcion());

        doc.setEstadoDocumento(estadoDoc);

        UsuarioVo usuarioVo = file.getUsuario();
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        usuario.setIdUsuario(usuarioVo.getId());
        usuario.setUserName(usuarioVo.getUserName());

        doc.setUsuario(usuario);

        doc.setRutaCloudDocumento(file.getRutaCloudDocumento());
        doc.setCasillaOrigen(file.getCasillaOrigen());
        doc.setCasillaDestino(file.getCasillaDestino());
        doc.setCantidadRegistros(file.getCantidadRegistros());
        doc.setMontoTotalDocumento(file.getMontoTotalDocumento());
        return doc;
    }

}
```

And this is the error after performing *mvn test*:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.374 s <<< FAILURE! - in cl.rdbc.filetransfer.services.ServiceLayerTests
[ERROR] whenCreateDocument_ReturnDocument  Time elapsed: 0.037 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at cl.rdbc.filetransfer.services.ServiceLayerTests.whenCreateDocument_ReturnDocument(ServiceLayerTests.java:52)
```

The line with the error coincides with this one:

```
DocumentoVo actualDocument = documentsService.uploadFile(docVo);
```

Comment: The null pointer exception is probably coming from inside that method, and not the service object being null. I am guessing the stubbing of the `save()` method is not working and thus the method call of `save()` returns null. If you debug the test and step into to the code that’s probably what happens. Does the `Documento` class have an `equals()` method?

Comment: @ArhoHuttunen yes, Documento has a equals method. I'll try debuging